# Why 2D-index not working?

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, geolocation, mongodb-query

I have a large set of documents like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("572e33baf082e29c46cadb7b"),
    "nodes" : [ 
        [ 
            39.2035598754883, 
            51.6601028442383
        ], 
        [ 
            39.2038421630859, 
            51.6602439880371
        ], 
        [ 
            39.2038688659668, 
            51.6602249145508
        ]
    ]
}
```

And I want to search documents by coordinates. My query is:

> db.points.find({nodes: {$elemMatch: {$geoWithin:
>   {$box: [[39.1981, 51.660], [39.206, 51.664]]}}}})

I also added an index

> db.points.createIndex( { "nodes": "2d" } )

but it has no effect. Collection stats:

```
{
    "ns" : "base.points",
    "count" : 215583,
    "size" : 61338720,
    "avgObjSize" : 284,
    "storageSize" : 86310912,
    "numExtents" : 10,
    "nindexes" : 3,
    "lastExtentSize" : 27869184,
    "paddingFactor" : 1.0,
    "systemFlags" : 0,
    "userFlags" : 1,
    "totalIndexSize" : 39759888,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 7006832,
        "nodes_2d" : 26719168
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

And explain:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 61,
    "nscannedObjects" : 215583,
    "nscanned" : 215583,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 215583,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 215583,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 1684,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 1466,
    "server" : "DEVELOP-PC:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple:

> db.points.find({nodes: {$geoWithin: {$box: [[39.1981, 51.660],
>   [39.206, 51.664]]}}})

should be excluded from the query `$elemMatch` and the index will work correctly